# Start several scripts at once but still have output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run several scripts at once and have them output to different files but I can't get my code to work.

Code:

```
@echo off
start "" EXECUTIONSCRIPT1 >> "DIRECTORY\run1.log"
start "" EXECUTIONSCRIPT2 >> "DIRECTORY\run2.log"
start "" EXECUTIONSCRIPT3 >> "DIRECTORY\run3.log"
```

The scripts themselves perform whatever they need to do just fine, however, I can't get them to output anything to their files even though it's specified in the code.

If I remove (start "") they all run one after the other and they all output to their log files but that defeats the whole purpose of having them all run at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the `>>` is taking the output of the `start` command. In order for the `>`s to get passed as an argument instead of being activated immediately, they need to be escaped.

```
@echo off
start "" EXECUTIONSCRIPT1 ^>^> "DIRECTORY\run1.log"
start "" EXECUTIONSCRIPT2 ^>^> "DIRECTORY\run2.log"
start "" EXECUTIONSCRIPT3 ^>^> "DIRECTORY\run3.log"
```

Comment: THAT IS INCREDIBLE! I would never have gotten that through fiddling and searching online by myself. That worked a treat! Could you give me some sort of documentation that explains that? Thanks a lot, @SomethingDark!

Comment: Could this also be turned to something that outputs both standard and errors?

Comment: I'm going to try to put 2>&1 at the end and hope that doesn't mess with anything or something weird like "the start also outputs to that". Aha

Comment: @MarlXtianMonzonMarcera `start ""` runs the command in a subshell then returns right away, so it can't redirect the output because it doesn't control the console anymore

Comment: The `2>&1` should be `2^>&1` (or maybe `2^>^&1`?) for the same reason you need to escape the `>>`

Comment: Thanks again, @SomethingDark! It's the second one (2^>^&1) that worked.

Comment: Thanks, @phuclv! That helped me understand a bit.